# Is it a good idea to have SQL table entries refer to other ids in the same table?

Tags: sql, database-design, e-commerce, categories, relationship

I'm designing a table for product categories for a kinda-e-commerce site. The table currently looks a bit like this:

```
| id |     name    | level |    value    | parent_id |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | Food        |   0   | food        |    NULL   |
| 2  | Phone       |   0   | phone       |    NULL   |
| 3  | Thing       |   0   | thing       |    NULL   |
| 4  | Pasta       |   1   | pasta       |     1     |
| 5  | Apple       |   1   | apple       |     2     |
| 6  | SubThing    |   1   | subthing    |     3     |
| 7  | Tagliatelle |   2   | tagliatelle |     4     |
| 8  | iPhone 11   |   2   | iphone_11   |     5     |
| 9  | SubSubThing |   2   | subsubthing |     6     |
```

Basically I don't want to create a whole new table and map the relationships every time people want to add a new sub-level to the category structure, and rely on `level` and `parent_id` columns to let my code know how to do with this category and what its parent is. I'm completely new to model designing and this is the best I could come up with. Is there any downside to this self-referencing structure that I'm just too noob to realize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain the sub level (child) will only ever be referenced by that single row or parent then the design should suffice. You may run into issues if multiple child elements need to roll up into that parent entity.